# jquery ui sortable droppable, and css floating

Tags: jquery, user-interface, containers, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I'm attempting to create a simple "game":
I have a sortable list on the right, which contains items that can be dropped into a droppable.

This is what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/geY2Z/1/

code, script:

```
function func() {
    $("#list").sortable({});
    $("#container").droppable({
        accept: ".drag",
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
            $("#s").html("drop!" + count++);
            ui.helper.clone().appendTo("#container").draggable({containment:"#container"});
            ui.helper.remove();
        }
    });
}
func();
```

html:

```
<div id='list' style='width:100px;height:200px;overflow: auto; border:1px solid red; float: right;'>
    <div class='drag'><span>dragme</span></div>
    <div class='drag'><span>dragme</span></div>
</div>
<div id='container' style='float:left;border:1px solid black; width:400px;height:500px;'></div>
```

The problems are these:
1. I want the elements wil still be draggable after they dropped in the container, but to constrain movement to the container, so I used draggable as well - is that the best way?

2.I want the container and the list not to change their position even if the window is resized. You'll notice that if you resize the window, the container will breakline after the list, and the dragged items inside the container will move out. I don't want that to happen, I want the container to always be in one line with the list, always on left, in fixed width and height. If the window is resized, I want to see scrollbar for the container, with the items inside. I've tried to use `overflow:auto`, but no success. I think that the `float` property is not good in this case, so what should I use instead?

**EDIT:**

Another problem:
I've noticed that it's possible to drop the item "half" inside the container (out of the container border), and drop event is still fired and the item is not reverted. How can I prevent that, to restrict it into the container or revert?
For example, try to drag the item and place it somewhat out of the container, it will be accepted, but then if it will be dragged again, it will be restricted inside the container, as I want on the first drag from the sortable list.

Comment: Please post the code in the question

Comment: I've linked to jsfiddle, but fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RE: #1 - Yes, that's perfectly acceptable.

RE: #2 - You want to wrap your two floating `<div>` elements in a parent `<div>` which has a fixed width; this will prevent your wrapping. I'd also add a DIV with a clear fix after the floating ones, just to be safe. Here's what your new markup would look like:

```
<div style="width:510px">
    ... <!-- Your existing floating DIVs -->
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Updated jsFiddle, forked from yours: http://jsfiddle.net/YqAP7/

Comment: Very much thanks to you.  Couldn't imagine it would be that simple. Though you've answered my question, I have another question, updated my question. It's regard item being drop "half inside". I might open another question if I should..